# Read a file from a folder and extract a specific key from the file and save as in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and the task I am performing is to extract a specific key value from a list of `.iris` ( which contains the list of nested dictionary format) files in a specific directory.

I wanted to extract the specific value and save it as a new `.csv` file and repeat it for all other files.

Below is my sample of `.iris` file from which I should extract only for the these keys `('uid','enabled','login','name')`.

```json
{"streamType":"user",
"uid":17182,
"enabled":true,
"login":"xyz",
"name":"abcdef",
"comment":"",
"authSms":"",
"email":"",
"phone":"",
"location":"",
"extraLdapOu":"",
"mand":997,
"global":{
"userAccount":"View",
"uid":"",
"retention":"No",
"enabled":"",
"messages":"Change"},
"grants":[{"mand":997,"role":1051,"passOnToSubMand":true}],
```

I am trying to convert the `.iris` file to `.json` and reading the files one by, but unfortunately, I am not getting the exact output as desired.

Please, could anyone help me?

---

My code *(added from comments)*:

```py
import os
import csv

path = ''
os.chdir(path) 

# Read iris File 
def read_iris_file(file_path): 
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f: 
        print(f.read())
        
# iterate through all files
for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is in iris format or not
    if file.endswith(".iris"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
        # call read iris file function
        print(read_iris_file(file_path))
```

Comment: Kindly share your work which you have done so far. Maybe I can help you

Comment: Help you on what? you are asking the solution of one of the homework you got from your professor in college  .

Comment: import os
import csv

path = ''
os.chdir(path)
  
# Read iris File
def read_iris_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
  
# iterate through all file
for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is in iris format or not
    if file.endswith(".iris"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
  
        # call read iris file function
        print(read_iris_file(file_path))    I am able to read the files from a folder and displaying in a dictionary format and after that i got struck to read the file and extract the specific key/values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files contain data in JSON format, so we can use built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse it. To iterate over files with certain extension you can use [`pathlib.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with next pattern `"*.iris"`. Then we can use [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and pass `"ignore"` to `extrasaction` argument which will make `DictWriter` ignore keys which we don't need and write only those which we passed to `fieldnames` argument.

**Code:**

```py
import csv
import json
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"path/to/folder")
keys = "uid", "enabled", "login", "name"
with open(path / "result.csv", "w", newline="") as out_f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_f, fieldnames=keys, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    for file in path.glob("*.iris"):
        with open(file) as inp_f:
            data = json.load(inp_f)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below (the key point here is loading the iris file using ast)

```
import ast

fields = ('uid','enabled','login','name')
with open('my.iris') as f1:
  data = ast.literal_eval(f1.read())
with open('my.csv','w') as f2:
  f2.write(','.join(fields) + '\n')
  f2.write(','.join(data[f] for f in fields) + '\n')
```

my.csv

```
uid,enabled,login,name
17182,true,xyz,abcdef
```

Comment: Why not to use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to work with *csv* format?

Comment: @OlvinRoght That is an option for sure but since we data set is tiny I decided to skip  it.

Comment: You can also use print functionality in that case. `print(*fields, sep=",", file=f2)` ; `print(*itemgetter(*fields)(data), sep=",", file=f2)`

Comment: As per the requirement i should read the multiple *.iris files from a folder and create a .csv file with specific keys as it has mentioned in the above code and I am trying to incorporate the above code to my file read code and after executing it has been selecting last file from the directory and load into csv file but should read all the files one by one from the directory and load into csv files with the above fields